# Missing lib karate-jersey:1.0.0 when including karate-junit5:1.0.0

Tags: java, karate

the new version of the karate suite was released on 15.03.2021. Our renovatebot created a merge request but our pipeline always fails since karate-jersey:1.0.0 can not be found.

Does anyone know where is this lib? I've searched in multiple maven repositories and I found nothing.

Thanks
Paulo

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's gone. Read the release notes please: https://github.com/intuit/karate/wiki/1.0-upgrade-guide

[image]